# Jackson converts Set to List when converting POJO to Map

Tags: java, jackson

Hy,

I have a (POJO) model object, which I need to convert to a `Map` some times.
I'm currently using Jackson for that as its a good library I also use in other places quite a lot.
It all works fine except for variables in my POJO, which are `Set`s, as Jackson converts them to `List`s in the resulting `Map`.
That won't do though, as I need the properties of a `Set` for my use-cases.

Here is a short unit test to show the issue:

```java
  @Getter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public class O {
    private Set<String> abc;

  }

  @Test
  void test() throws Exception {

    Map map = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(new O(Set.of("abc", "def")), Map.class);
    assertFalse(List.class.isAssignableFrom(map.get("abc").getClass())); // Already fails
    assertTrue(Set.class.isAssignableFrom(map.get("abc").getClass()));
  }
```

How can I get Jackson to use to original Collection type of the variable?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Well, think of this conversion as being similar to POJO -> JSON -> MAP. Since JSON doesn't have any notion of sets but only arrays (which are mapped to lists) that's why you get that behavior. You might be able to store the actual collection type in some kind of meta-property (Jackson has some configuration for this) but it might not work with maps anyway. Why do you want to convert `O` to a map anyway while expecting the exact same value types to be used?

Comment: could you try using a jackson TypeReference instance of Map.class when calling convertValue? Something like `new TypeReference<Map<String, String>> {}`. This is a way of defining a type that avoids type erasure. -- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map might help

Comment: @Thomas I see, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. I need it for different things, but one example is where I have a String "template" and I want to fill in the data of the pojo, which is easiest using a Map (think Velocity Template just much much simpler)

Comment: @PJFanning If I understand it correctly, I could do that, if every field in my pojo was a Set (then using `new TypeReference<Map<String, Set>>()`), but it has fields with all kinds of types (String, int, long, even Lists)

Comment: Well, a string template wouldn't (or let's say shouldn't) care whether you'd be using a list or set. Since the main properties that distinguish sets from lists are on the "write" side of things (no duplicates, no null values in some cases) a reading template should actually not even have to know you're using a set or list here - just `Collection` should do (order should also not be a requirement due to you wanting to use a set which is unordered by definition).

Comment: Btw, you could also have a look at bean introspection for cases where you want to access data via property names.

Comment: @Thomas You have a point there.. I came across it in my unit tests, where there are now two possible outcomes for the Strings and the one I asserted was by chance the wrong one. But yeah, I think I only have the issue in UnitTests, so I will just change them and be fine